# "...instead of below / beneath / underneath / under / lower it."

Tags: grammar

First off, I would like to say that I know that there's a similar thread posted [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78355/under-below-beneath-underneath-behind-others) and I have read all the answers over there but mine is a bit bit different than that one because it is asking for the word after "instead of" and how should it be grammaticaly. And it has a different context too so please don't mark it as duplicate. Please.

So When referring to the position of a "floating" (meaning this is not on a page / notebook rather it is on a packaging's surface, where there are no lines to write on) sentence (a slogan) in relation to the position of a floating word (the product's name) and both are on the same front surface / face / side of the packaging of the product, which one would be correct and which ones are plainly wrong to say? (state in AE and BE if there's a difference)

1) "The name should be above the slogan instead of **below** it."

2) "The name should be above the slogan instead of **underneath** it."

3) "The name should be above the slogan instead of **beneath** it."

4) "The name should be above the slogan instead of **under** it."

5) "The name should be above the slogan instead of **lower** it."

The meaning intended here is that the name of the product in a packaging should be written first then the slogan after (below) it.

Note that the word "above" here is clearly specifying direction which is "up" and not implying "in front of". So the use of the word "behind" here is clearly also out of context.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use “below” or “under” to refer to the position in front of a product. "The slogan goes under the product name" would be my primary phrasing. Everything except "lower" is accurate though.

Comment: Doesn't "under" often creates an ambiguous meaning to you?

Comment: No. Keep in mind though English is my native tongue and I'm here to help. This is my opinion as such. I suppose, if we were discussing a box, it could be taken to mean on the bottom of the box, or on a separate sheet of paper on the table below it. I would be shocked if it was interpreted like that though. Up would mean the package is oriented so the writing is legible and the top of the package, under means between the product name and the bottom of the package.

Comment: I mean like if I say "under this heading" which meaning is being conveyed? Also is "instead of below it." is it grammatically correct?

Comment: Typically "under this heading" would refer to the information being attached as information as part of the set of information defined by the heading. Such as the text of chapter one of a book being "under" chapter one. In this context, under is being used to reference the heading and to attach information to it. "Below the heading" typically does not imply attachment, although it may still be so. Instead it is a direct reference to physical placement relative to the other information.

Comment: In regards to physical placement, between "below" and "under", which one has a lower level of ambiguity upon usage? Also any difference in meaning between No. 2 & 4 (underneath and under) for the OP question context?

Comment: With regards to physical position on the front of, say a box of cereal, that would depend on context but my understanding is you are meaning strictly the placement with no implied reference to attachment to a heading. In this case, if you are more comfortable with below, you will be fine. This will not create ambiguity. The only ambiguity I can foresee is the difference between "directly below" and "below" the first one is more specific about the exact placement.